# OpenCV supporting multiple resolutions

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I need to process some images to find objects on it.
so, the images can be in different resolution and quality. I thinking about how to process it via the same algorithms if possible.
the options I have:

- resize images (big images makes smaller) - in this case the process will take less time, but we can lose some details
- check algorithms, and chose the better "pre-edit filter sets" that can be applied for each resolution - guess can get good results but it will be difficult to support and enhance
- chose the same "pre-edit filter sets" and calculate values for filters

which is the best one?

Comment: do you want to find the **same** object in **different** images?

Comment: @Jeru Luke, yes. different images that can be provided in different resolutions

Comment: have you thought of using SIFT or SURF?

Comment: OK do you have any sample images you are working with?

Comment: "SIFT or SURF", - no, I didn't. will check, thank you. will update question and add sample images a bit later

Comment: Ok try ORB first that is open source